# How can you wrap iOS apps?

Tags: ios, ios7, dylib, dlopen

I'm working on research that requires me to be able to load an iOS app from a custom piece of code running on the device.  I more or less want to modify the current sandbox and then run an existing application in it.  I would rather not modify the application, although I realize at some point I'll at least have to re-sign it.

Mocana can apparently do this with their "MAP" technique, but I've not seen any papers or presentations explaining the technical details of how this is accomplished.

I was attempting to dlopen an application's executable and then dlsym on it's main.  That moderately works, but requires a debug version of the application.  Trying to use an archived version is problematic since the symbol table is separate.  Not sure if there is a way to merge the symbol table with the executable. Tried unsuccessfully with lipo, but no real luck (says the architectures are the same and won't merge).

Any direction or good publications would be appreciated.